# Launch an specific app on android phone via WearOS app

Tags: android, wear-os

I am working on a WearOS application. This app is connected to an android device via bluetooth. I have created an app in that android device too. I want to launch that android app from my watch app by a button. I don't know how can I make my WearOS app to launch an specific app that I created in the android device.

I have learned to launch implicit intent using androidx.wear.remote.interactions.RemoteActivityHelper but it seems to work only with implicit intents.

Comment: Yep, use a specific URL that you know launches that app via an implicit intent.

Comment: Can you be more specific? @YuriSchimke